# How To Add Same CSS Class To Change A Width

Tags: jquery, html, css, magento, magento-1.7

I have a problem on my website. I can't figure out why the CSS code is written to control the whole menu drop down.

If I put the css class width to **none;** It'll put the alignment of the brands category drop-down in the correct 2 column 5 row format. But it lets the product images in the category drop down overlay each other.

**BUT!! When I Set it to;**

```
       .menu .col_1 {
width: 200px;

 }
```

[image]

That screws up the format of the brands category which should be 2 columns + 5 rows .

What code should I write in the CSS file to change this?

The site is ;

```
.menu-box {
background: none no-repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
border-top: 1px solid #999999;
/*    clear: both;*/
float: left;
margin-top: 1px;
position: relative !important;
}
.menu {
font-size: 12px;
list-style: none;
width: 960px;
}
.menu li {
float: left;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
padding: 5px 10px 1px;
color: #FFF;
height: 45px;
}
.menu li div li {
height: auto;
}
.menu li:hover {
z-index: 2;
cursor: pointer;
background: none no-repeat scroll 0 0 #888;
    }
.menu li small {
color: #F5F5F5;
display: block;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: lowercase;
/*line-height: 10px;*/
}
.menu li a {
padding-top: 2px;
color: #FAFAFA;
outline: 0 none;
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
}
.menu li:hover a {
color: #FFF;
}
.menu li div span {
color: #000000;
cursor: default;
font-size: 14px;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu li div a {
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: none;
}
.menu li.sales div span {
color:#E7160F;
}
.menu li div span.subtitle {
padding-left: 8px;
}
.menu li .drop {
padding-right: 21px;
}
.menu li.home {
background: url("../images/cdd_btnhome.png") no-repeat scroll 20px 10px transparent;
border-right: 1px solid #FFC24F;
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
width: 30px;
}
.menu li.home:hover {
background: url("../images/cdd_btnhome.png") no-repeat scroll 20px 10px #888;
}
/*.menu li.sales {
background: #000000;
}*/
.menu li.sales:hover {
background: #E7160F;
}
/*.menu li.sales a {
color: #FFFFFF;
}*/
.menu li.sales a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.menu li.sales ul li a:hover {
color: #E7160F;
}
.menu li.support:hover {
background: #888;
}
.menu li.support {
/*background: #000000;*/
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 29px;
}
/*.menu li.support a {
color: #FFFFFF;
}*/
.menu li.support a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.menu li.support ul li a:hover {
color: #000000;
}
.menu li:hover .drop {
padding-right: 21px;
background: none;
}
.menu li:hover div a {
color: #666;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 0 0 0 8px;
}
.menu li:hover div a:hover {
background: #EEEEEE;
}
.menu li ul li a:hover {
color: #000000;
}
/* Right aligned menu item */
.menu .right {
border: none;
float: right;
right: 0;
margin-right: 0;
}
.menu .support {
border: medium none !important;
float: right;
margin-right: 0;
right: 0;
}
/**************** Flyout Menu */
/* Left & right aligned common styles */
.menu .dropdown_1columns,
.menu .dropdown_2columns,
.menu .dropdown_3columns,
.menu .dropdown_4columns,
.menu .dropdown_5columns {
margin: 4px auto;
left: -999em;
position: absolute;
background: #FFFFFF;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -3px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -3px #999;
box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -3px #999;
border: 10px solid #888;
padding: 10px;
text-align: left;
cursor: default;
}
.menu .dropdown_1columns_sales,
.menu .dropdown_2columns_sales,
.menu .dropdown_3columns_sales,
.menu .dropdown_4columns_sales,
.menu .dropdown_5columns_sales {
margin: 4px auto;
left: -999em;
position: absolute;
background: #FFFFFF;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -3px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -3px #999;
box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -3px #999;
border: 10px solid #E7160F;
padding: 10px;
text-align: left;
cursor: default;
}
.menu .dropdown_1columns_support {
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 10px solid #888;
padding: 10px;
margin: 4px auto;
position: absolute;
left: -999em;
text-align: left;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -3px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -3px #999;
box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -3px #999;
cursor: default;
}
/*.level1 {
border-bottom: 1px dashed #DDDDDD;
}*/
/* Drop Downs Sizes */
*/.menu .dropdown_1columns_sales {
width: 169px;
}
.menu .dropdown_2columns_sales {
width: 368px;
}
.menu .dropdown_3columns_sales {
width: 500px;
}
.menu .dropdown_4columns_sales {
width: 670px;
}
.menu .dropdown_5columns_sales {
width: 920px; /*765px;*/
}
.menu .dropdown_1columns_support {
width: 176px;
}
/* Showing Drop Down on Mouse Hover - Left aligned */
.menu li:hover .dropdown_1columns_sales,
.menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns_sales,
.menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns_sales,
.menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns_sales,
.menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns_sales {
left: 0;
top: 43px;
}
.menu li:hover .dropdown_1columns_support {
left: 0;
top: 43px;
}
/* Drop Downs Sizes */
.menu .dropdown_1columns {
width: 169px;
}
.menu .dropdown_2columns {
width: 368px;
}
.menu .dropdown_3columns {
width: 500px;
}
.menu .dropdown_4columns {
width: 670px;
}
.menu .dropdown_5columns {
width: 920px; /*765px;*/
}
/* Showing Drop Down on Mouse Hover - Left aligned */
.menu li:hover .dropdown_1columns,
.menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns,
.menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns,
.menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns,
.menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns {
left: 0;
top: 43px;
}
/* Showing Drop Down on Mouse Hover - Right aligned */
.menu li .align_right {
}
.menu li:hover .align_right {
left: auto;
right: 0;
top: 43px;
}
.menu li .align_right_support {
}
.menu li:hover .align_right_support {
left: auto;
right: 0;
top: 43px;
}
/* Columns Sizes */
.menu .col_1,
.menu .col_2,
.menu .col_3,
.menu .col_4,
.menu .col_5 {
display: inline;
float: left;
position: relative;
/*margin: 0 0 10px;*/
min-height: 60px;
padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
.menu .col_1_support {
display: inline;
float: left;
position: relative;
/*margin: 0 0 10px;*/
min-height: 60px;
padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
.menu .col_1_support {
width: 177px;
}
.menu .col_1 {
width: 200px;

}
.menu .col_2 {
width: 368px;
}
.menu .col_3 {
width: 500px;
}
.menu .col_4 {
width: 670px;
}
.menu .col_5 {
width: 920px;
}
/* IMPORTANT */
/* Use the firstcolumn class for the items that stick to the left edge of the dropdown         */
.menu .firstcolumn {
margin-left: 0; /* Clearing margin & left */
clear: left;
border-right: medium none;
}
/**************** Flyout Menu Content */
.menu p,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu h2,
.menu h3 {
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 18px;
text-align: left;
}
.menu li.right {
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height: 21px;
text-align: right;
/*border-right: 1px solid #FFC24F;*/
}
.menu .col_1_support ul {
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height: 21px;
text-align: left;
/*border-right: 1px solid #FFC24F;*/
}
.menu .col_1_support li.divider {
background: url("../images/cdd_hr.gif") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;
/*border-right: 1px solid #FFC24F;*/
}
.menu .col_1_support li.divider {
height: 1px;
margin: 10px 0;
}
.menu p {
color: #999999;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.menu .strong {
font-weight: bold;
}
.menu .italic {
font-style: italic;
}
.menu h2 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: -1px;
font-size: 21px;
line-height: 21px;
margin-top: 7px;
margin-bottom: 14px;
padding-bottom: 14px;
}
.menu h3 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 21px;
margin-top: 7px;
margin-bottom: 14px;
padding-bottom: 7px;
}
.menu .pusher {
/* Use this pucher if you want to give more vertical spacing between your rows of     content */
margin-top: 18px;
}
/* Images styles */
.menu .imgshadow_light {
/* Better style on light background */
background: #FFFFFF;
padding: 4px;
border: 1px solid #999999;
margin-top: 5px;
}
.menu .img_left {
/* Image sticks to the left */
width: auto;
float: left;
margin: 2px 15px 15px 0;
}
.menu .img_right {
/* Image sticks to the right */
width: auto;
float: right;
margin: 2px 0 15px 15px;
}
/* Standard lists styles */
.menu li ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}
.menu li ul li {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
position: relative;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
float: left;
text-align: left;
width: 169px;
}
.menu li ul li:hover {
background: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
/* 2-Levels Flyout */
.menu .levels {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
}
.menu .levels li li,
.menu .levels li li:hover {
width: 150px;
padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
margin: 0 0 0 1px;
}
.menu .levels ul {
/* First level Flyout */
position: absolute;
z-index: 500;
top: -23px;
left: 100%;
display: none;
width: 180px;
background: #FFFFFF;
margin: 15px 0 0 0;
padding: 6px 0 6px 0;
}
.menu .levels ul ul {
top: -6px;
left: 100%;
width: 180px;
margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}
.menu li.position-right-li {
border-right: 1px solid #FFC24F;
position: static;
}
.menu li:hover div.position-right {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
left: auto;
top: 47px;
}
.menu .levels li:hover {
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 100;
}
.menu .levels li:hover ul ul,
.menu .levels li li:hover ul ul {
display: none;
}
.menu .levels li:hover ul,
.menu .levels li li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
.menu form {
margin: 0 0 12px 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any padding or margins on those lists? if so you would need to create a class like .last for the last items on that row and set the padding or margin to 0

Comment: That's most of the menu.css file. Margins are set to Zero can you write your code how it would be formatted to be added to that CSS file?

Comment: Can you please do a jsfiddle maybe or provide the link to the page so i can look for you?

Comment: It is on the index of my website when your mouse hovers over the menu. Please scroll up to my question to find page.

Comment: .menu li.last { padding: 5px 0 1px } and apply class .last for teh last item

Comment: If you can show me how the code will look that'd be helpful cause I was  randomly copy and pasting that code you gave me in different areas with firebugs and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer div 'dropdown_5columns' has a width of 920px.

You are trying to fit 5 x 200px in there... that is just to large.
If you specify :  .menu .col_1 { width: 160px; } they will fit just fine in there.

Comment: Yes you are right but I'm trying to integrate 160px and 200px as 160 px will screw the other menu right next to it up.

Comment: Indeed, but you are trying to make a 4 column and 5 column layout with exactly the same css rules. You'll gonna have to differentiate them some how. You have a class 'dropdown_5columns', why not make a class dropdown_4columns and have that one set the 200px width?

Comment: If only I where a good coder I could understand what you are telling me. Im a damn noobie . I bought the theme and I'm an SEO expert. Im clueless.

Comment: Why don't you elaborate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I will try it: At the very end of the CSS file that you put in your question, I suggest you add this code:

```
.menu li ul li {
    width: inherit;
}

.menu .col_1 {
    min-width: 0px;
}
ul.menu > li > div > div > ul > li div.slideshow-box > ul {
    width: 924px;
    position:relative;
    left:-12px;
}
ul.menu > li > div > div > ul > li div.slideshow-box > ul > li.item {
    display: inline;
    float: inherit;
}
.slideshow-box > ul > li.item > div > div.item-box {
    margin-left: 12px;
}
```

It changes the width settings so that the width is not constrained at all and the content will take up as much width as it needs. Then it adds additional layout for the menu with the big product layout boxes to make them sit in a line.

***Edit
I added a bit more CSS and some notes in the section above, but seriously, I think you should bring on board someone who knows more CSS and HTML or you may find setting up your store in Magento a very long and painful process.